# How to delete aws ECR repository which contain images through cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

How to delete aws ECR repository which contain images through cloudformation? getting below error while deleting it.

**The repository with name 'test' in registry with id '**********' cannot be deleted because it still contains images**

Answer (score 2):

Leaving my approach to solve this using Python's boto3 client. (1) Empty repository and then (2) delete stack.

```py
import boto3
ecr_client = boto3.client('ecr')
...

# Apply only to ecr cfn template
if '-ecr' in stack_name:
    print('Deleting existing images...')
    image_ids = ecr_client.list_images(repositoryName=ECR_REPO_NAME)['imageIds']
    ecr_client.batch_delete_image(
        repositoryName=ECR_REPO_NAME,
        imageIds=image_ids
    )
    print('ECR repository is now empty.')

# Now delete stack containing ECR repository
delete_stack(**cf_template)
```

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it all via CloudFormation, but you can do it with a single cli command, instead of resorting to python or multiple image delete commands.

```
aws ecr delete-repository \
  --repository-name <reponame> \
  --force
```

The --force flag will cause the deletion of the images also:

```
   --force | --no-force (boolean)
      If a repository contains images, forces the deletion.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by first deleting all images in ECR and then going back to CloudFormation and deleting again. Instructions for deleting images are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/delete_image.html. After I did that, I was able to head back to CloudFormation and delete with no problems.